# HTTPS issue in Nodejs and Angular port collision

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ssl, dns

I'm installing a SSL certificate for my Angular + node app, running on Apache. I already generated the key, CSR and bought the certificate in GoDaddy, all good.

I installed it in Apache and configured the VirtualHost for 80 and 443. The website redirects when entering via https perfectly.

The issue comes when my web app tries to reach the Node server via https://www.mydomain/api. This returns the html rather than hitting the node server and fetching my DB information. If I hit it using the IP rather than the domain, it works well because I am able to specify the port, however it gives me an error because the certificate cannot be verified (because the IP doesn't match the domain of the cert which makes sense)

This is because https is using port 443, in which my Angular app is running, versus my node server that is running in 8443. How can I do it so when I point to https://www.mydomain/api it hits the node server in 8443 vs the Angular app? Is it okay to share domains within the 2 apps? (I only bought 1 SSL certificate). Should I change this in the VirtualHosts? How?

I want to clarify that before moving to https, everything was working perfectly in http.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain
    #Redirect / https://mydomain/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName mydomain

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/private/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/server.crt

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And express:

```
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');
var ca = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.pem', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca};
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

As summary, I need both server and web running through https, I only have 1 domain and I am struggling to understand how the ports should be referenced in each case.

EDIT: I kept looking and found that this what I might be looking for, but is not working:

```
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /api https://myip:8443/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api https://myip:8443/api
```

I'd really appreciate some recommendations on good practices here!

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is experiencing this, I resolved it using Proxy, here is the full Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /api https://myip/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api https://myip/api
</VirtualHost>
```